# Solr 4 Spatial Query Filter still returns documents out of range

Tags: solr, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query, solr4

The Target is to perform multisort by score then distance, and to limit to a radius of 0.14 degrees I perform the following query:

```
localhost:8983/solr/coll1/select?sortsq={! score=distance}locations:"Intersects(Circle(34.0031792,-118.3082034 d=0.14))"&fl=score,distdeg:query($sortsq),*&facet=true&sort=score desc,query($sortsq) asc&indent=on&wt=xml&version=2.2&rows=10&start=0&q=text:*&facet.field=xxxxx&fq=fieldname:"filterValue"
```

All the documents matching the query are returned, whether it is within the circle or not, but the ones that within the 0.14 degrees returns the distance (distdeg), and the others does not have that field returned.

How can I omit the non-intersecting documents?

locations field declaration:

```
<fieldType name="geo_field"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
               spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
               distErrPct="0.025"
               maxDistErr="0.000009"
               units="degrees"
 />
```

**Update:**
Working Version of the query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/coll1/select?getDist={! score=distance}locations:"Intersects(Circle(34.0031792,-118.3082034 d=0.14))"&fl=score,distdeg:query($getDist),*&facet=true&sort=score desc&indent=on&wt=xml&version=2.2&rows=10&start=0&q=*:*&boost=query({! score=distdeg filter=false v=$getDist)&fq=locations:"Intersects(Circle(34.0031792,-118.3082034 d=0.14))",states:"CA"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't actually spatially filtering at all.  A solr search matches documents based on the 'q' (the query string from the user; it scores) and 'fq' (filter queries, which don't score), nothing else.  Neither your 'q' nor your 'fq' refers to the spatial filter that you put into the sortsq param.  See the docs: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4#Search

Your q=text:* is weird; what do you intend?  All docs?  That query might appear to work but don't do that, as its not doing what you think its doing; it's finding all docs that have any value in that field (not fast to compute), which isn't necessary all docs.  Best practice is defType=edismax and q.alt=*:* and qf=text (assuming that's your text search field) which will match all docs if you don't have a query string to supply.

By the way, it doesn't make any sense to follow score sorting with anything else.  There are a huge variety of floating point values and consequently the distance will rarely be consulted.  You probably want to boost scores by distance instead. Here's an example of that: &boost=query({! score=recipDistance filter=false v=$spatialfilter}) (substitute the name of your parameter that has the spatial search for spatialFilter).

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, it makes more sense to boost the distance, but I really want to understand that syntax, is there any documentation for boost syntax and the function calculating the distance. I updated the question with the working query syntax, without dismax though yet. If there is any improvements I can make please tell me, thank you so much for your time and efforts

Comment: Your updated query uses the 'boost' param correctly but you didn't specify the defType=edismax (edismax looks for the boost param, nothing else). And I noticed a trailing ",states:"CA"" on your 'fq' which is wrong as the comma shouldn't be there, maybe you means 'OR' ?  I posted a link to the Solr 4 spatial page on Solr's wiki. I should add an example depicting boosting.  You might want to read my book or look at other information (e.g. the wiki) on dismax/edismax.

Comment: You are right, I've ommited the , replaced with AND and enabled dismax query parser, but the confusion comes here, in the docs, it is written that the qf parameter defines specific fields to return which is the same as fl parameter but with the ability to boost in query time, I've tried to use qf parameter but it doesn't work with degdist:query($getDist). I'm not sure which to use fl or qf, or both fl for fields and qf to boost some fields? also there is boost parameter that you specified, Can it handle multiple boosts? Shall I use it or use qf for boosting fields?

Comment: Only 'fl' (field list) lists the fields to return in search results.  'qf' (query fields) specifies which fields that the query 'q' (keyword search, not spatial) will be applied to, and it also allows you to specify which of those fields are more relevant. 'boost' is for a function query, the result of which will be multiplied to the document's score (more or less) to boost some documents more than others. It can be repeated if desired.  I suggest starting with the essential parameters and verify they behave as you understand, then incrementally add more.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much, you saved me hours of frustration. I'm definitely buying the book.